# Creating a New Hive Table with a Conditional Column Based off of Another table

Tags: sql, hive

I'm trying to create a new Hive table based off of an existing table. I need help with an if statement that would allow me to create one merged column from 2 separate columns in the original table. The columns new_name & old_item and uh_new_name and uh_old_item have the same data and I'd like to have a single column. I can't alter the table since its Hive. As an end result I need the id, open_time, then the combo of the columns.

Here is my code to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE CIs
  AS SELECT id, open_time, new_name, uh_new_name, old_item, uh_old_item from sm
        where open_time like '2016%' or open_time like '2017%'
        order by open_time desc;
```

Here is the general logic behind the combined column I need:

```
If id like 'AB%' then old_item else new_item as combo_code
IF id like 'AB%' then uh_old_item else uh_new_item as combo_name
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just needs a simple case statements as part of your select:

```
case when id like 'AB%' then old_item else new_item end as combo_code,
case when id like 'AB%' then uh_old_item else uh_new_item end as combo_name
```